# how to find the coefficient for the construction of the linear regression model (using Fourier )?

Tags: r, regression

My data is :

```
86180, 86180, 86270, 86160, 86190, 86160, 86160, 86130, 86160, 86250, 86200, 86180, 86220, 86200, 86240, 86270, 86300, 86300, 86480, 86770, 86790, 86750, 86710, 86660, 86620, 86640, 86620, 86590, 86540, 86470, 86480, 86520, 86340, 85870, 85920, 86080, 85930, 85950, 85660, 85830, 85920, 85900, 85930, 85990, 85860, 86040, 86210, 86260, 86460, 86270, 86310, 86240, 86310, 86350, 86330, 86060, 86140, 86200, 86080, 85830, 85700, 85680, 85610, 85670, 85790, 85770, 85730, 85550, 85390, 85380, 85620, 85630, 85640, 85670, 85680, 85740, 85740, 85660, 85590, 85880, 85890, 85840, 85840, 85770, 85570, 85510, 85390, 85380, 85400, 85330, 85250, 85280, 85200, 85390, 85440, 85180, 85330, 85200, 85260, 85370, 85370, 85460, 85410, 85490, 85340, 85180, 85140, 85160, 85220, 85440, 85490, 85360, 85300, 85330, 85270, 85270, 85130, 84920, 85050, 84860, 85030, 85090, 84890, 84950, 85220, 84950, 84710, 84740, 85070, 84940, 84840
```

I'm trying to build  linear model that includes a sine wave:

```
ggplot(someData, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x + sin(x/4.7))
```

Looks ok:

[image]

But i want to calculate coefficient -> 4.7 automatically, for this I try to use Fourier Transform:

```
fftin <- arrange(someData, x)$y
fftres <- fft(fftin)
barplot(Mod(fftres))
```

[image]

And at this moment I am stuck, I don't know how to put in readable form.. and at least figure out that my coefficient = 4.7 . Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're on to something, but you need some more knowledge of the FFT properties to refine your approach. First of all, let's read in your data:

```
y <- c(86180, 86180, 86270, 86160, 86190, 86160, 86160, 86130, 86160, 
       86250, 86200, 86180, 86220, 86200, 86240, 86270, 86300, 86300, 
       86480, 86770, 86790, 86750, 86710, 86660, 86620, 86640, 86620, 
       86590, 86540, 86470, 86480, 86520, 86340, 85870, 85920, 86080, 
       85930, 85950, 85660, 85830, 85920, 85900, 85930, 85990, 85860, 
       86040, 86210, 86260, 86460, 86270, 86310, 86240, 86310, 86350, 
       86330, 86060, 86140, 86200, 86080, 85830, 85700, 85680, 85610, 
       85670, 85790, 85770, 85730, 85550, 85390, 85380, 85620, 85630, 
       85640, 85670, 85680, 85740, 85740, 85660, 85590, 85880, 85890, 
       85840, 85840, 85770, 85570, 85510, 85390, 85380, 85400, 85330, 
       85250, 85280, 85200, 85390, 85440, 85180, 85330, 85200, 85260, 
       85370, 85370, 85460, 85410, 85490, 85340, 85180, 85140, 85160, 
       85220, 85440, 85490, 85360, 85300, 85330, 85270, 85270, 85130, 
       84920, 85050, 84860, 85030, 85090, 84890, 84950, 85220, 84950, 
       84710, 84740, 85070, 84940, 84840)
someData <- data.frame(x = seq_along(y), y = y)
N <- length(someData$x)
L <- someData$x[N]-someData$x[1]
```

Now, **before** computing the FFT, you should subtract the linear trend from your data . The reason is that only the variation around a decreasing linear trend seems to be approximately sinusoidal. the FFT is just a fast algorithm for the DFT, and the DFT treats the input values as if they were one cycle of a periodic function. If you don't subtract the linear trend, then you will be reconstructing a function which, after a shift equal to `L`, goes back to its initial value in `x[1]`. This would be totally at odds with a function whose average keeps decreasing with `x`, which seems to be the case for your data. Let's subtract the linear trend and compute the FFT:

```
trend <- lm(y ~ x, data = someData)
someData$detrended <- someData$y-trend$fitted.values
fft_in <- someData$detrended
fft_out <- fft(fft_in)
barplot(Mod(fft_out[2 : (N/2 + 1)]))
```

[image]

There! See? Looking much better now. 
After subtracting the linear trend, it looks like only the first 5 harmonics are important. The rest of the harmonics have comparatively less energy, and could be due to the noise which corrupts your data. Since the fundamental frequency is

```
omega <- 2*pi/L
```

this means that we can fit a model with frequencies $\omega,2\omega\dots,5\omega$, and of course the linear trend we subtracted before. Thus we get:

```
model <- lm(y ~ x + sin(omega*x) + cos(omega*x) +
            sin(2*omega*x) + cos(2*omega*x) +
            sin(3*omega*x) + cos(3*omega*x) +
            sin(4*omega*x) + cos(4*omega*x) +
            sin(5*omega*x) + cos(5*omega*x),
            data = someData)
```

Let's have a look at the results:

```
> summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + sin(omega * x) + cos(omega * x) + sin(2 * 
    omega * x) + cos(2 * omega * x) + sin(3 * omega * x) + cos(3 * 
    omega * x) + sin(4 * omega * x) + cos(4 * omega * x) + sin(5 * 
    omega * x) + cos(5 * omega * x), data = someData)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-258.424  -64.063    8.794   73.853  254.689 

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        86493.6198    49.1226 1760.771  < 2e-16 ***
x                    -10.8986     0.7287  -14.956  < 2e-16 ***
sin(omega * x)       107.1861    33.2883    3.220  0.00165 ** 
cos(omega * x)       -76.9001    14.1635   -5.429 3.03e-07 ***
sin(2 * omega * x)    -1.4059    20.6435   -0.068  0.94582    
cos(2 * omega * x)   -78.0693    14.1639   -5.512 2.09e-07 ***
sin(3 * omega * x)    -8.1287    17.3160   -0.469  0.63962    
cos(3 * omega * x)   -97.5967    14.1646   -6.890 2.83e-10 ***
sin(4 * omega * x)  -122.1106    15.9880   -7.638 6.16e-12 ***
cos(4 * omega * x)  -109.1215    14.1657   -7.703 4.38e-12 ***
sin(5 * omega * x)    27.0228    15.3337    1.762  0.08058 .  
cos(5 * omega * x)   161.3981    14.1669   11.393  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 114.4 on 119 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9551,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.951 
F-statistic: 230.2 on 11 and 119 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Not bad! Most terms are extremely significant, and the adjusted $R^2$ is 0.95 with 119 residual degrees of freedom. It doesn't make sense to remove the non-significant terms: it would be "fishing for significance". Instead, let's have a look at the plot:

```
x <- seq(someData$x[1], someData$x[N], by = 0.01)
myfit <- data.frame(x = x)
myfit$y <- predict(model, newdata = myfit)
ggplot(someData, aes(x, y)) +
geom_point() +
geom_line(data = myfit, color = "blue")
```

[image]

Everything looks fine, but...the trigonometric polynomial part of the model is of course periodic, while your detrended data seem to show some sort of decay (exponential?). We can see this better if we model, and plot, only the detrended data:

```
detrended_model <- lm(detrended ~ sin(omega*x) + cos(omega*x) +
                                  sin(2*omega*x) + cos(2*omega*x) +
                                  sin(3*omega*x) + cos(3*omega*x) +
                                  sin(4*omega*x) + cos(4*omega*x) +
                                  sin(5*omega*x) + cos(5*omega*x),
                                  data = someData)
 myfit$detrended <- predict(detrended_model, newdata = myfit)
 ggplot(someData, aes(x, y = detrended)) +
        geom_point() +
        geom_line(data = myfit, aes(y = detrended), color = "blue")
```

[image]

You see clearly that the part of your model which represents the variation around the linear trend is periodic. Thus, after a shift in `x` equal to `L`, it will become "large" again, instead than to keep decaying. Thus this model is probably not suited for extrapolation.

**EDIT**: the reason why both sine and cosine terms are fitted is due to the use of complex exponential in the expression of Fourier series, and [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) which gives the relationship between complex exponentials and trigonometric functions. However, a simpler argument can be given, which is basically equivalent but avoids the recourse to complex analysis. Once we have seen from the FFT that most of the energy of the detrended data seems to be concentrated at the first 5 multiples of the fundamental frequency, we can think to fit the original data with the sum of a linear polynomial and a sum of sines (or cosines), where both the amplitude and the phase are unknown:

$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \sum_{i=1}^5 M_i \sin{(i\omega x+\phi_i)} + \epsilon$$

The problem in estimating such a model is that it's nonlinear in the parameters $\phi_i$ (the phases). However, since

$$\sin{(i\omega x + \phi_i)}=\sin{i\omega x}\cos{\phi_i}+\cos{i\omega x}\sin{\phi_i}=A_i\sin{i\omega x}+B_i\cos{i\omega x}$$

we can reparametrize our model as the following linear model:

$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \sum_{i=1}^5 (C_i \sin{(i\omega x)}+D_i \cos{(i\omega x)}) + \epsilon$$

Since the model is linear, we can now estimate its parameters with `lm`.

Comment: Thank you for great answer!, But I have a problem with understanding the: ...sin(omega*x) + cos(omega*x) + sin(2*omega*x) + cos(2*omega*x)... 1) Why you decide to use sin+cos together? 2) the first 5 bars you defined as 5ω, its mean, need to use 5 time "sin+cos" and each time increase harmonic by 1 ? 3) what method do you recommend to define the peak values ? for this huge function =(

Comment: 4) and last question, how you will  build model, when after FFT  significant value will have: №1, 4, 9 bar?

Comment: omega <- 2*pi/L - L in this case = 1?

Comment: @MaxUsanin, as I wrote in the first code chunk, `L <- someData$x[N]-someData$x[1]`. Looking at the `x` scale of your plot, I assumed that `x` is an index, which is a common assumption in modeling equispaced time series. Thus, in this case, `someData$x[1]`=1 and `someData$x[N]`=131, thus  `L` = 130. If you rescale your abscissas so that `someData$x[1]`=0 and `someData$x[N]`=1, then `L` = 130. I'll modify my answer to reply to some of your questions in the comments. For the questions in your remaining comments, please open a new question.

Comment: but i don't understand why you repeat cos+sin 5 time... if we look on plot - we will see sin(4*omega*x) + cos(4*omega*x) only 1 time can be enough..

Comment: Not at all! Try fitting the `y ~ x + sin(4*omega*x) + cos(4*omega*x)`. The adjusted $R^2$ goes down to 0.85. That's _way_ worse than my model. If you prefer, compute the 5-fold CV: that will also be lower than that of my model. I'm all for simple models and against fishing for significance, but there are limits! With your reasoning, you could even just fit the `y ~ x` and be content [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] with an adjusted $R^2$ of 0.8. Also, the FFT amplitude plot clearly shows that the first 5 modes have significant energy. If you're not familiar with FFT and related plot, I suggest you google it or you ask a question on the Mathematics forum. The only way I could understand your point of view, is if you had additional holdout data which you didn't show us and where the `y ~ x + sin(4*omega*x) + cos(4*omega*x)` does significantly better than the model with the first 5 modes. But then of course the question changes completely: you explicitly asked to use FFT to get the significant modes.

Comment: I will prepare new topic, because my aims is 1) recognise, this is wave 2) get peaks of the wave 3) direction of wave, and of course prepare some model which will do automatically

Comment: It is why fft good choose for me (I think), but a complex formula is not suited (cos + cos + N time) ... because will be difficult to find peaks, it's my assumption, and next topic will be how to find peaks of the sinusoid in this case -> ...sin(2*omega*x) + cos(2*omega*x) +
            sin(3*omega*x) + cos(3*omega*x).. or simplify